# Need jQuery datepicker calendar to adjust a little bit to left

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, datepicker

I couldn't set the margin-right in datepicker div and it looks like this.. hidden under the scrollbar of window

[image]

I need it a little left so it is completely visible.

I have this css:

```
.Datetext {
    background-position-x:right; background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-image:url(../Images/Cal.png); background-size:18px;
}

#ui-datepicker-div { font-size:12px; }
```

and this in my aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modified Date" ItemStyle-Width="10%" FooterStyle-Width="10%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="dtModDate" CssClass="Datetext2" Width="98%" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DateAdded")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="dtModDate2" CssClass="Datetext2" Width="98%" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the font size of your calender?

Comment: I don't want to decrease font size. That size is agreed one. 
I need datepicker div to appear a little bit on the left.

Comment: Then set the div margin right to some pixel.

Comment: I did believing that would do it but to surprise nothing happened. I set margin right in #ui-datepicker-div

Comment: Then just try by setting `margin:5px` instead of `margin-right:`

Comment: margin:-15px worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

margin:-15px worked......